# How to interpret the result of the command "od -b file"

Tags: java, unix

I was trying to see how JAVA's DataInputStream and DataOutputStream works with bytes. I wrote an integer, 1000, into the file. When I use "od -b file" to see the file content as stream of bytes, I got the following result:

```
wangyifan:~/Documents/cs180/draft$ od -b lowlevel  
0000000   000 000 003 350                                                
0000004
```

When I translated `000 000 003 350` into decimal it was not `1000`.
So what is the correct way to interpret this result?
Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but it is, in big endian.  First, 0350 octal is 232 decimal.  3*256 + 232 = 1000.

Comment: Can you please explain why is it 0350 and how did you get 256? Thanks.

Comment: 0350 is octal for 232. Multiplying by 256 is the equivalent of shifting left 8 bits. You should know all this. When you 'translated `000 000 003 350` into decimal you didn't do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**od** is a program for displaying ("dumping") data in various human-readable output formats. The name is an acronym for "octal dump" since it defaults to printing in the **octal** data format. It can also displaying output in a variety of other formats, including hexadecimal, decimal, and ASCII. It is useful for visualizing data that isn't in a human-readable format, like the executable code of a program.

The answer is in comment by *Joe Z*

**Here `-b` option to `od` command means One-byte octal display.Display the input offset in hexadecimal,
             followed by sixteen space-separated, three column, zero-filled,
             bytes of input data, in octal, per line.**

is in **Big Endian**

0350 octal is 232 decimal.

> HOW?

(3x8^2)+(5x8^1)+(0x8^0) = 232

And now look at what i have written above that **the input offset in hexadecimal,
             followed by sixteen space-separated** thus `16^2 = 256`

Now 3 is what HEX, So `3 HEX = 3 DEC` Thus `256*3`

So Overall equation is,

`3*256 + 232 = 1000` which is what you had entered in file.

Comment: I understand how 232 is calculated, but why is 3 multiplied by 256? Why not 8^3? And why is there a zero in front of 350? Isn't one byte a 3-digit octal? Thank you

Comment: @Yifan_Wang Why do you think it should be 8^3?

Comment: @Yifan_Wang:  It's multiplied by 256 because each byte is 8 bits wide. 2^8 = 256.  As far as the leading zero:  That's just matching C (and related languages) syntax.  Both 350 and 0350 are octal numbers if you _tell_ people they're octal.  The leading 0 is the convention used to tell the compiler it's octal, much like 0x tells it it's hex.

Comment: @EJP Because I thought 003 350 means 3350 in octal, or 11011101000 in binary. So it's not?

Comment: @JoeZ I understand multiplying 256 with 8 bits. So here 003 350 doesn't mean 003350 in octal or 000000011011101000 in binary?

Comment: @Yifan_Wang : The space indicates it's two separate bytes:  003, 0350.  If you were to write out the full 16-bit number in octal, it would actually be 01750.